# apache removes the first / from url

Tags: apache-2.4

For example, `https://subdom.mysite.com/contact_us/` --> `https://subdom.mysite.comcontact_us/`

These are the only rewrite rules that I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

Some background: I'm using an apache webserver to host an angularjs 1.6 web application. Changing the last two lines seems to break the webapp, in the sense that I can't reload the page anymore..

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042434/why-is-apache-permanent-redirect-removing-the-slash-between-the-domain-and-the-p), but their issue stemmed from http urls, which isn't the case here.

Here are the server logs:

> [Tue Aug 13 18:20:18.897503 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 1] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
>   
>   [Tue Aug 13 18:20:18.924270 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
>   
>   [Tue Aug 13 18:20:18.938867 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.0.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   
>   [Tue Aug 13 18:20:18.938916 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
>   
>    - - [13/Aug/2019:18:20:43 +0000] "GET /contact_us HTTP/1.1" 302 357
>   
>   [13/Aug/2019:18:20:43 +0000] TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET /contact_us HTTP/1.1" 357
>   
>    - - [13/Aug/2019:18:20:46 +0000] "GET /contact_us HTTP/1.1" 302 228

Comment: I'm assuming that what you mean is that apache is redirecting you to the url with the removed slash. As your rewrite rules don't show any redirects (`[R]`), it's being done elsewhere, probably happening inside the application.

Comment: you're right! For some reason, the redirect was coming from my `<VirtualHost *:80>` block, anyway, I added a `/` at the end of the redirected url and it's working now